# Extract text based on annots from PDF using Python and PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to read the below PDF programmatically using Python to extract useful information.

[image]

Here, the "attachments" are basically links that point to specific pages inside the same PDF. I came to know that these are called "annots" and there is a way to extract them using `PyPDF2` library.

My end goal is to read the whole PDF attachment by attachment where each attachment could span across multiple pages. I've tried below:

```
# creating a pdf reader object
pdfReader: PdfReader = PdfReader(pdfFileObj)

# Read annots from pdf
start = 0
end = 2
while start < end:
    try:
        for annot in pdfReader.pages[start]["/Annots"]:
            print(annot.getObject())  # (1)
            print("")
    except:
        # there are no annotations on this page
        pass
```

I was hoping that `annot.getObject()` or something like `annot.extract_text()` would give me the full content of the relevant pages but it is not so. Going through `annot` object doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: @KJ that's the first thing I did as I was 99% sure these are just a bunch of attachments bundled together. However, that's not the case sadly: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/1645#issuecomment-1437876996

I'm at the point of scratching my last few remaining hairs. I don't want to end up writing a hacky spaghetti half-perfect code.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample the annot attachments symbols are a red herring, It looks like they were attached in the past but then flattened into the whole PDF. A secondary issue adding to annotation confusion, is that many of the 409 internal and external linked filenames when downloaded did not agree between internal and external nomenclature, usually a sign of poor merging. There are 372 different Fonts included thus showing, one file has ben merged from many. Posibly had been a former "portfolio" composed of different attached files, but now simply appended as pages.

[image]

[image]

From either the field data file or the pdf we can see which is the first page to extract for each attachment
`type C:\Apps\PDF\2023-02-09-04-31-12.fdf |find "/D ["|more`
so the answer DESTINATIONS start off 2,4,6,8,9 thus some are 2 pages some are 1 some may be many !

```
/D [2 /FitH 10000]
/D [2 /FitH 10000]
/D [2 /FitH 10000]
/D [4 /FitH 10000]
/D [4 /FitH 10000]
/D [4 /FitH 10000]
/D [6 /FitH 10000]
/D [6 /FitH 10000]
/D [6 /FitH 10000]
/D [8 /FitH 10000]
/D [8 /FitH 10000]
/D [8 /FitH 10000]
/D [9 /FitH 10000]
/D [9 /FitH 10000]
/D [9 /FitH 10000]
```